# two Case statements inside each other and I want to return to the first case

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to put a case statement inside another case statement like this
And having it so the user can return to the first case statement if they want

```
read choice
case $choice in
    1)
       read pattern
       case $pattern in

              pattern1)
                      Statement()
                      ;;

              pattern2)
                      Statement(return to the first case)
                      ;;

            *)
            echo "Error"
            ;;
            esac

            ;;

    2)

            echo "test"
            ;;

    3)

            break
            ;;

            *)
            echo "error"
            ;;
            esac
```

Comment: Use a loop enclosing all that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
while true; do
   read -rp "Your Question? [1|2|3] " choice
   case $choice in
```

Comment: does this let me go back into the case $choice when I am inside case $pattern ?

Comment: Yes .. It will pop you back to `read -rp "Your Question? [1|2|3] " choice`